# How do I perform an atomic operation using the Datomic database?

Tags: database, atomic, datomic

TL;DR I want the function: "update Y ONLY IF Y=10", otherwise it fails.

Example: imagine the timeline being T1, T2 and T3. At time T1, the entity X contains the attribute Y=10, at time T2 the attribute is Y=14. My aim is to apply a complex operation in Y (assume that this operation is the sum of 1). I read the value of Y at T1, which is 10 and place this value in a queue to be processed. At T3, when the complex operation is completed and the result is 11, I will update the attribute Y. If I simply update the attribute, the value Y=14 that was at T2, it will be mistakenly discarded. However, at T3, upon updating, I want to be sure that the final value is Y=10, otherwise I have to read Y=14 at T2 for reprocessing.

I know about [Database Functions](http://docs.datomic.com/database-functions.html) to make atomic read-modify-update processing, but this approach is not good if the operation is complex and need to be done distributed (after put in a queue).

What I want is something equivalent to [Conditional Writes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html) in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to Felipe's comment "a transaction function that insert only if or throw exception", can you not just use the built-in one [see :db.fn/cas](http://docs.datomic.com/transactions.html)?

Comment: @RodyD, perfect, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You could run the ensure process peer-side, validate for a certain basis T, and then check the basis T of the database in the transaction. So the computationally complex or expensive code is handled peer-side and the transaction function is only responsible for the basis T validation.

For anything that matches the standard use case (e.g., your example in your description), [Database Functions](http://docs.datomic.com/database-functions.html) are the correct and canonical answer.

The built-in :db.fn/cas function is available and is now documented at http://docs.datomic.com/transactions.html

Comment: Thank you Ben! I'll create a transaction function that make this: insert ONLY <IF condition> or throw an exception otherwise. It should solve my problem.

Comment: The built-in fn do exactly this: :db.fn/cas (from @RoryD answer)

Comment: We recently updated the documentation to include the :db.fn/cas builtin. I've updated my answer to reflect.